# Overlapping Spans

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, overlapping

I am trying to write a query that reorders date ranges around particular spans. It should do something that looks like this

```
Row   Rank   Begin Date   End Date
1     B      3/24/13      11/1/13
2     A      10/30/13     4/9/15
3     B      3/26/15      12/31/15
```

and have it become

```
Row   Rank   Begin Date   End Date
1     B      3/24/13      10/29/13
2     A      10/30/13     4/9/15
3     B      4/10/15      12/31/15
```

To explain further, the dates in row 2 is ranked higher (A>B), so the dates in row 1 and 3 have to change around the dates in row 2 in order to avoid overlap in dates.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Do you mean you are using SQL Server? Please tag your question with your RDBMS. Also, are you simply looking for help in merging the dates, or is there more to your question? Do we need to understand your rankings?

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am looking to update the dates. And no, there isn't much to the ranking except A > B. And there is only A and B. Date ranges with rank A should remain untouched.

Comment: What if you have two consecutive `'B'` ranked records with overlapping dates?

Comment: Overlapping B ranked dates are okay. I am concerned with B ranked dates overlapping with A ranked dates.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query to update the table.

```
Update table_name 
set End_Date = DATEADD(day, -1, select Begin_Date from Table_name where   
Row_number = '2')
where row = 1;
```

You need to change the row numbers every time you run the query. Let me know If this works for you.

I suggest First create a View

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tempview AS
SELECT row, begin_date FROM table_name
WHERE row > 1;
```

Then Use this query to update all the row. If may not update just the first row.

```
Update table_name 
set End_Date = DATEADD(day, -1, select Begin_Date from tempview)
```

Hope this works

Comment: Thanks, this does work. However I am looking to apply this over a very large data set (700 rows), so I would want something more automated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT Row, Rank, BeginDate, EndDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BeginDate) AS rn
   FROM mytable
), ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT c1.Row, c1.Rank, c1.BeginDate, c1.EndDate,
          c2.Rank AS pRank, c2.EndDate AS pEndDate, 
          c3.Rank AS nRank, c3.BeginDate AS nBeginDate
   FROM CTE AS c1
   LEFT JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
   LEFT JOIN CTE AS c3 ON c1.rn = c3.rn - 1
   WHERE c1.Rank = 'B'
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET BeginDate = CASE 
                   WHEN pEndDate IS NULL 
                      THEN BeginDate
                   WHEN (pEndDate >= BeginDate) AND (pRank = 'A') 
                      THEN DATEADD(d, 1, pEndDate)
                   ELSE BeginDate
                END,
    EndDate = CASE 
                   WHEN nBeginDate IS NULL 
                      THEN EndDate
                   WHEN (nBeginDate <= EndDate) AND (nRank = 'A') 
                      THEN DATEADD(d, -1, nBeginDate)
                   ELSE EndDate
                END
```

A `CTE` is initially constructed to assign consecutive, ascending numbers to every record of your table. `ROW_NUMBER()` window function is used for this purpose.

Using this `CTE` as a basis we construct `ToUpdate`. This latter `CTE` contains date values of *current* as well as *previous* and *next* records. 
This `LEFT JOIN`:

```
LEFT JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
```

is used to join together with *previous* record, whereas this one:

```
LEFT JOIN CTE AS c3 ON c1.rn = c3.rn - 1
```

is used to join together with *next* record.

Using `CASE` expressions we can now easily identify overlaps, and, in case there is one, perform an update.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34ced/3)